# Php script allows me to add one country. Any way to add 2 countries

Tags: javascript, php, html

PHP script allows me to add one country. Any way to add 2 countries.

```
if( $visitor['country_code']!='UK' ) {
    $this->redirectTo( osc_base_url() );
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Please provide additional details what you exactly want to do.

Comment: As written, all countries except UK are redirected to `osc_bas_url()`.  I presume you're wanting to add another country that will not be redirected?

Answer (score 0):

The logic can be confusing if you try to use the existing if statement, because the way we would say it in real life would be,

> "unless your country code is UK, you're going to be redirected."

But since PHP doesn't have `unless`, we have to state it the opposite way with an `if` statement:

> "If your country code *isn't* UK, you're going to be redirected."

When you add another country, it can get rather confusing.  If we said it with unless, it would be

> "Unless your country code is UK **or** xyz, you're going to be redirected."

But using `if`, you would have to say,

> "If your country code isn't UK ***AND*** isn't xyz, you're going to be redirected."

So to put that into code,

```
if( $visitor['country_code']!='UK' && $visitor['country_code']!= 'xyz') {
    $this->redirectTo( osc_base_url() );
}
```

Another, easier to understand (maybe) way to do it would be to make an array of country codes that would not be redirected, and then check to make sure that `$visitor['country_code']` does not contain one of those values:

```
$countries_to_pass = array('UK','xyz');
if(!in_array($visitor['country_code'],$countries_to_pass) ) {
    $this->redirectTo( osc_base_url() );
}
```

This avoids the negative-negative logic and would allow more countries to *easily* be added to the list of allowed countries.